# Value of type 'Any' has no member 'title'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to show a list of data from an array inside a list but is not working and i'm getting this error below

There is any other way to display this data from the array to the list?

Thanks :-)

The error:
`Value of type 'Any' has no member 'title'`

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import Foundation

struct goal: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var description: String
    var endDate: String
    var category: String
}


struct ActiveGoalsView: View {
    
    @State var goals = []
    @State var ref = Database.database().reference()
    @State private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()

    func getData() {
        ref.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "noid").child("goals").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                
                let snap1 = snap as! DataSnapshot
                
                let goalId = snap1.childSnapshot(forPath: "goalId").value
                let description = snap1.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value
                let endDate = snap1.childSnapshot(forPath: "end_date").value
                let category = snap1.childSnapshot(forPath: "category").value
                
                goals.append(goal(id: goalId as! String, description: description as! String, endDate: endDate as! String, category: category as! String))
                
                //print(snap1.childSnapshot(forPath: "goalId").value)
                //print(snap)
                
                print(goals)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            ForEach(goals, id: \.self) {goal in
                Text(goal.title)
            }
            
            List() {
                
                Button(action: {getData()}, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
                
                /*
                ForEach(goals, id: \.self) {goals in
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text(goals)
                        })
                    }
                }*/
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct ActiveGoalsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ActiveGoalsView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define what type `goals` should contain -- you just used the `[]`, which implies `Any`.

```
@State var goals = []
```

So, replace that with this:

```
@State var goals: [goal] = []
```

Now that Swift knows that `goals` is an array of `goal` (which conforms to `Identifiable`), you can remove the `, id: \.self` in your `ForEach`. Also, `Text(goal.title)` doesn't make sense because `goal` doesn't have a property called `title`. Maybe you meant `description`?

Note: You should capitalize structs like `goal` -> `Goal`.

Note 2: `Text(goal)` also doesn't make sense. You probably meant `Text(goal.description)`.

Comment: Is not working. And when i try to print only the goal array i'm getting other errors like: `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'goal' conform to 'Hashable'` and `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'goal' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

Comment: There is any other way to display the data from the array??

Comment: @GSepetadelis try replacing `ForEach(goals, id: \.self)` with `ForEach(goals) `

Comment: now i'm getting this error on the Text() line: `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'goal' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

Comment: @GSepetadelis use `Text(goal.description)` instead of `Text(goal)`